# Cant use a linq expression,The entity or complex type '' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to use a linq expression that has a join.I tried with the var result and with  List result  =     , but with both i got the error.

The entity or complex type 'OdontoService.Dal.Consultas' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query. What is the problem, i cant do that?

Code below:

```
var result = 
    context.consultas
    .Join(context.pacientes, left => left.id_paciente, right => right.id_paciente, 
       (left, right) => new { TableAColumns = left, TableBColumns = right }).Select(m => new Consultas
       {
                        id_consulta = m.TableAColumns.id_consulta,
                        id_paciente = m.TableAColumns.id_paciente,
                        comentarios = m.TableAColumns.comentarios,
           dt_alteracao = m.TableAColumns.dt_alteracao,
           dt_inclusao = m.TableAColumns.dt_inclusao,
           procedimento = m.TableAColumns.procedimento,
           data_consulta = m.TableAColumns.data_consulta,
           flg_Situacao = m.TableAColumns.flg_Situacao,
           nome_paciente = m.TableBColumns.nome_paciente
       }).ToList();
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a duplicate to that, because the solution from it is, what the asker here did - use an anonymous type...

Comment: @vinicius Could you show us the models?